# How to present list/table of properties in material design?

Tags: material-design, material-ui

I am refactoring an old web app into React and Material-UI, and I find myself stuck when trying to find the proper way of presenting a "property table". I have looked into several data table implementations, but neither a data table nor Material-UI's List seems to be the right tool for the work.

*Data tables* are meant for each row having the same properties (columns) repated for different entities, whilst I need a kind of table where each row is a *key+value* presentation. I will call it a *property table* unless someone can tell me there is already a better name.

Below is a picture of current view in the refactored app (contains only test data). I realize I might need to think differently and not just copy the old structures.

So what would be the correct way to present a similar list of properties with Material Design?

[image: A "property table" listing key+value properties]

Comment: I'm searching for a good example of this myself. I have yet to find one.

Answer (score 7):

I seem to find no explicit component or view type for my *"property table"*, so I will simply make a table with Material-UI `<Table>`component, and skip the header.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In M2 and M3, the way to handle this is with two-line [lists](https://m3.material.io/components/lists/overview), with the headline as the property name and the supporting text as the value.

Android 13 uses this pattern throughout the settings menu. Note the de-emphasized headline text when a property is not clickable.

[image: A screenshot of Android 13 settings screen showing device details such as IMEI number and Android version using Material Design's List component.]